# Matching any character followed by not numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I am not good at RegEx. Though it seems very simple to achieve but I am not able to find out the way to match any characters followed by not numbers. I am trying with negative lookahead. If I use any word it is working as expected but if I try to match any character with square bracket, it is failing.

```js
var pattern = /sample(?!\d)/;
console.log(pattern.test("sample324")); //false
var pattern = /[a-z]+(?!\d)/;
console.log(pattern.test("sample324")); //true but expect false
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem is that `[a-z]+(?!\d)` will let it match any 1+ characters not followed by a digit, so it will match `sampl` in your input satisfying assertion of non-digit at next position.

You may use this regex with a negative lookahead:

```
/^(?!.+\d)/
```

This will fail the match if a digit appears anywhere in input after 1+ of any character.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hYIkTS/2)

For **better efficiency**, you may use this regex as well:

```
/^(?!\D+\d)/
```

Which fails if there 1+ non-digits followed by a digit *anywhere* in input.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may work:

```
var pattern = /[^0-9]/.test('mystring9')
```